# Iphone Application terminate due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger, nserror

I have an application in which i use this code for save data in local prefences.

```
-(IBAction)radio_button:(id)sender{
switch ( ((UIButton*)sender).tag ){
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    case 0:
    {
        [button0 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox_Checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button0.selected=TRUE;   
        [defaults setInteger: 0 forKey:@"tag_button0"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        NSLog(@"Data saved");



        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox_Checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button1.selected=TRUE;            
        [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"tag_button1"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        NSLog(@"Data saved");


        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox_Checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button2.selected=TRUE;            
        [defaults setInteger:2 forKey:@"tag_button2"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        NSLog(@"Data saved");

        break;
    } 
}
```

}
  When i run the application then i get error message which i shown below.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIControlTargetAction setInteger:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181dd0'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x35f08c7b **exceptionPreprocess + 114
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30186ee8 objc_exception_throw + 40
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x35f0a3e3 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 98
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x35eaf467 __*forwarding*** + 506
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x35eaf220 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
>       5   Congnitive_Appointment_Timer        0x0000d03d -[Set_Routine_Screen radio_button:] + 252
>       6   CoreFoundation                      0x35eada43 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 26
>       7   UIKit                               0x3384af20 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 136
>       8   UIKit                               0x3384ae88 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 40
>       9   UIKit                               0x3384ae50 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 52
>       10  UIKit                               0x3384aaa0 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 536
>       11  UIKit                               0x3384b5cc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 460
>       12  UIKit                               0x3383ceb0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 588
>       13  UIKit                               0x3383c4e4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 396
>       14  UIKit                               0x3381fc9c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 452
>       15  UIKit                               0x3381f3b4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6824
>       16  GraphicsServices                    0x35262c88 PurpleEventCallback + 1048
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x35e9a5cb **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 28
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x35e9a589 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 164
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c835 __CFRunLoopRun + 580
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c50b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 226
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x35e8c419 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 60
>       22  GraphicsServices                    0x35261d24 GSEventRunModal + 196
>       23  UIKit                               0x3386557c -[UIApplication _run] + 588
>       24  UIKit                               0x33862558 UIApplicationMain + 972
>       25  Congnitive_Appointment_Timer        0x00002c19 main + 72
>       26  Congnitive_Appointment_Timer        0x00002b98 start + 52
>   )
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

What is error in above code?

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring your defaults variable inside of the switch.  Move it to outside the switch

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
switch ( ((UIButton*)sender).tag ){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use This One

-(IBAction)radio_button:(id)sender{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    switch ( ((UIButton*)sender).tag ){

        case 0:
        {

            btn1.selected=TRUE;   
            [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"tag_button0"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            NSLog(@"Data saved");



            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {

            btn2.selected=TRUE;            
            [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"tag_button1"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            NSLog(@"Data saved");


            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {

            btn3.selected=TRUE;            
            [defaults setInteger:2 forKey:@"tag_button2"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            NSLog(@"Data saved");

            break;
        } 
    }
}
```